# Shell script to open a set of URL's

Tags: shell, url, unix

I want to open a set of URL's in shell script and get the return status.
I tried gnome-open and xdg-open, but no luck

```
 xdg-open http://www.google.com
-bash: xdg-open: command not found


 gnome-open http://www.google.com
Error showing url: There was an error launching the default action command associated with this location.
```

I have an array of url's. I want to open them and if they are opening up without any error , show the status as running else not running.

```
 #!/bin/ksh
 urlArray=('http://url1:port1' 'http://url2:port2' 'http://url3:port3')
for url in "${urlArray[@]}"
 do 
   result=`curl $url | head -1`

    if (echo $result | grep '<?xml' >/dev/null 2>&1); then
        echo Running
    else
        echo Not Running
     fi
 done
```

If the url opens up correctly, it will have the 1st line as `"<?xml version"` .Hence I want to grep this.

Comment: `gnome-open http://www.google.com` works fine. It's open with firefox program. Even in a KDE environment. Maybe you don't a default program associated with this?

Comment: "Open" as in visit them in a web browser? Most graphical browsers will not provide any error code, especially not for individual pages. If you just want to check whether the server is responding, maybe a textuaö browser like `w3m` or a simple command-line tool like `curl` might be closer to what you are looking for. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @tripleee I have updated my question with exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: And what is your question now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a default program associated for opening URLs.  Try:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=string /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command '/usr/bin/firefox %s'
```

This would set firefox as default (assuming it's available at `/usr/bin/firefox`).

And you don't seem to have `xdg-utils` installed which is why you see `xdg-open: command not found`

Comment: If Gnome is correctly installed, I would expect `xdg-open` to be there, too.

Comment: On somewhat older distros, gnome had no dependency (external or otherwise) on `xdg-utils`.